# IntelliJ IDEA change preview length of collapsed code

Tags: intellij-idea, preview, code-folding

Is there a way to increase the length of the preview/greyed-out code, whenever a block is being folded?

So instead of seeing:`ChangePas...ostRequest: <2 keys>` 

I'd like to see:`ChangePasswordPostRequest: <2 keys>`
[image]

Comment: Not at the moment, no. But I'm checking with the responsible developers on whether it can be made into an option.

Answer (score 2):

A new feature request was created to keep the length of the folded code preview where possible:

[IDEA-236809](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-236809)

Feel free to vote for it and leave comments.

Comment: Is it possible to comment on the feature request? Instead of choosing between showing or not showing the entire name, make it so you can set a maximum showable amount of characters in the settings. Because let's say you have some names with 200+ characters, that will fill your screen up and that's not something you want. But if you could limit it to e.g. 120 characters it will automatically trim/squash it on 120 characters:)

Comment: edit: I added it as a comment on the feature requests, when it gets implemented I'll update my question :)